# how to use Typescript in (Solution>Add>Existing Web Site ...) projects?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

[image: no typescript template in existing web site projects]

When i create a project by adding an existing web site project
there is no typescript template in (add->new file) .
What should i do ?

I'm using visual studio 2013 update 3 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the typescript website:

> Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 includes TypeScript. Visual Studio 2012
>   developers can install the TypeScript editor plugin to get rich
>   TypeScript tooling. There is also TypeScript support for other editors
>   available

http://www.typescriptlang.org/

It doesn't get installed as a template it is a plugin.

**UPDATED**

I opened my sample MVC 5 solution, right clicked on my Scripts folder and selected 'Add New Item'. In the dialog that pops up I selected from the treeview Visual C# -> Web -> Scripts. I select TypeScript File and click Add. If you have not added typescript to your project before you should get a message like this:

[image]

I'll guess that if you don't get that message the first time you add a typescript file to your project that something went wrong and this is why you cannot compile it properly.

Comment: for example when i create an empty asp.net project , typescript template is available in add>new file . but in an existing web site project there is no typescript (.ts) template file .

Comment: Are you saying there is no option to add a .ts file?

Comment: I'm updating my vs right now with update 3 but will check itout when done.